# My callback functions don't seem to fill in my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback, get

I have a problem with my callback functions. My code is supposed to make 16 GET requests to a REST API to pull 16 different JSON files. It then needs to parse each of these JSON's to a dictionary for that week's football table rankings, and ultimately save each entry into a 'dictionary of dictionaries', HistoricalTable, to give the league ranking for the past 16 weeks. However, when I run the associated callback functions, the various LeagueTable variables seem to work fine, but when I try and save these into the Historical Data, the final array appears to have the same LeagueTable entry for each, looking like this.

[Here is an image of the console output for my final table. Each entry should be different, whereas each entry seems to be the most recent week.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLGWK.jpg)

```
//This creates the modifier for the URL used in the GET request
var MatchDayList = []
for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
  MatchDayList[i] = i
}
MatchDayList.shift()

var HistoricalTable = {}
var LeagueTable = {}

// This executes the GET request
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/leagueTable/?matchday=' + MatchDayList[i],

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/leagueTable/?matchday=' + MatchDayList[i],
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': ''
      },
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        handleData(data)
      },

    });
}
//This function should append the retrieved JSON to the LeagueTable variable
function handleData(data) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    LeagueTable[data.standing[j].position] = data.standing[j].teamName
    LeagueTable[20] = data.matchday
  }
  saveData(LeagueTable)
}
//This function should save each LeagueTable matchday data into a bigger array, HistoricalTable
function saveData(LeagueTable) {
  HistoricalTable[LeagueTable[20]] = LeagueTable
  console.log(HistoricalTable)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single `LeagueTable` variable throughout the entire code. So every call to `handleData` populates the same `LeagueTable`, then tells `saveData` to store it in the main table. So you end up with 16 references to the same table.

To solve it, it should be enough to move the variable declaration inside `handleData` function:

```
    function handleData(data) {
      var LeagueTable = {};
      for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        LeagueTable[data.standing[j].position] = data.standing[j].teamName
        LeagueTable[20] = data.matchday
      }
      saveData(LeagueTable)
    }
```

On a side note, your `url` variable is not declared anywhere, so it ends up in the global scope, which is generally bad practice. Same with `i` indices inside your for loops.

Comment: This is wonderful! I've been staring at this for hours and couldn't work out the answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer!